# C# Rdlc report missing space in text

Tags: c#, rdlc

I had same problem with `rdlc` report.
When I render the report with **PDF** format, sometimes space character disappear in `textbox`.

```
byte[] mybytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out streams, out warnings);
```

[image: rdlc text error]

Answer (score 0):

Check the report's property called ConsumeContainerWhitespace and set it to true.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried to put ConsumeContainerWhitespace to true but the problem persists. What is strange is that sometimes it works